# Как достать объект из json pyhon2

Tags: python

Мне нужно достать объект из массива json, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вот Вам банальный пример. Допустим есть некая переменная `j` содержащая `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'aa': 'z1', 'bb': 'z2'}}` , получаем значения:

```
>>> print j["a"]
1
>>> print j["c"]
{'aa': 'z1', 'bb': 'z2'}
>>> print j["c"]["aa"]
z1
```

Если надо подробнее, то необходимо увидеть структуру Вашего json-списка.